# Threading timer with worker threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer

is it possible to use threading timer to fire worker threads on timer event?

I want use threading.Timer because I am intending to using a windows service triggered by time, but all the example code I see using timer are using callback/threadpool instead. But in my service, the task will be longer than a few seconds (up to a minutes) and involve rather complex logic rather than just update a few fields. I think that would justify my choice of workerthread rather than threadpool?

Comment: I didn't really testing Peter's solution, as that project has been hold off, but I will come back to test it once my hands get free. Please feel free to vote up or down Peter's solution of other means of feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I needed a collection of threading timers. If my window service was stopped I needed any ongoing timer callbacks to complete.

You can use a WaitHandle when you [dispose your timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx), allowing any ongoing callbacks to complete:

```
var onWait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
timer.Dispose(onWait);
....
onWait.WaitOne();
```

[Here is my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500263/monitor-multiple-threading-timers-after-disposal) I haven't run into any issues..yet. My callbacks do some heavy processing that would take up to 10-20 minutes to complete.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your suggested solution, I am no longer working on that project. It just been hold off, so I will probably coming back to it. On the mean time, by the look of it, it maybe working, and I will mark your solution as answer for now. Please be aware that I might provide my own solution or if others providing an working solution and your solution didn't apply to my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the call back and the task parallel library to fire off your task....
[Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

However I believe [this sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) is doing what you want... I know it uses a threadpool...

> "it executes in a separate thread pool
>   thread that is provided by the
>   system."

... but why is that bad???

Also the task parallel library basically does a similar thing...

> "Behind the scenes, tasks are queued
>   to the ThreadPool, which has been
>   enhanced with algorithms (like
>   hill-climbing) that determine and
>   adjust to the number of threads that
>   maximizes throughput. "

Comment: Probably Task Parallelism is a good idea, as I am moving off to another project, probably need a couple of days to find out how it works.

Comment: I am considering moving off from Threadpool as from what I've read, Threadpool is for effectively creating thread without much overhead, but will have less feature and control than create thread manually. I happened need to properly finalize my thread code when windows service stop, seems like more work need to do for Threadpool than Thread. Task parallelism seems like a interesting new thing from .Net 4, but if Task could do it, Threadpool should able to do it? I will probably trying to make Threadpool work first.